# PHP file to load vs. HTML with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is it better to do something like this:

```
//PHP FILE:
<html>
  <body>
    hi
    <?php
      //load first 50 comments from mysql
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or this:

```
//HTML FILE
<html>
  <body>
  hi
  <div id="hello">
  </body>
</html>

//JS file:
$(document).load(function() { //or whatever it is if not 'load', I can figure it out
  $.ajax( /*php call, receive JSON of the mysql data*/ );
});
```

I'm looking for both speed and space efficiency. Which is better - having a PHP file sending the entire HTML file, or have an HTML file sending the data in JSON format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Measure it. You can, at best, get opinionated answers. Speed and efficiency - too broad terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is too generic for SO, but here are my two cents.

If retrieving the list of comments is the only thing you will do on this page, definitely go with the first option. You will have one less request, and this is time you should want to keep.
But as soon as you need some real-time actions with this list of comments, let's say `update`, `create`, `delete`, you can easily see that these requests should only give you back the new data, not everything that is around and that hasn't been modified.
Each time an action is called you have a choice between refreshing a page and just refreshing a part of its content.

So I would think of it this way :

- If you have some data that need to be shown fast, go with first option. The content will be displayed with the page.
- As soon as you need to do actions that impact only a small part of your page, why would you bother to retrieve the full page again ? The fastest option will be an AJAX call.

So mix both, and for every situation, takes the one that best fits your needs.

**To match your example**

I would do this :

`echo` the full list of comments with your page.
The list is now displayed, just like you needed.

But AJAX calls will be the best fit for:

- Adding a new comment
- Updating an existing one
- Retrieving new comments
- Deleting an existing one.

The deletion is typically a good example. If an user deletes a comment, you can just hide it instantly, and send the request whenever you want. So it will actually be seen as `real-time` by the user, faster than anything you could do.

P.S. : In my recent  applications, where I use `AngularJS`, I would actually go `AJAX` requests for everything. But there is a good reason behind it : with this mechanism, I can use caching, since the content of my `HTML` page is `static`.
The static page will be sent faster, and then the content will then be loaded at the right places. But this choice needs to be benchmarked.
Also, important point, if you go this path, you have to realize that crawling bots (like `GoogleBot`) won't be able to load your content.

Comment: Was basically going to point out the same thing you just said. +1

Answer (score 0):

Let php echo it out for you. Both methods essentially have php echoing out the second step just does that through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I think using straight php and MySQL would be quicker and simpler than jquery, json, mysql and ajax. But I don't think the speed differences would be noticeable these days anyways...

Best to choose whatever system works best with your application and coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, in general, speed will be slower in the second option. Because it will do one more HTTP-query. If your DB is not large then use simple PHP script